# Aggregate by aggregate (ARRAY_AGG)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Let's say I have a simple table `agg_test` with 3 columns - `id`, `column_1` and `column_2`. Dataset, for example:

```
id|column_1|column_2
--------------------
 1|       1|       1
 2|       1|       2
 3|       1|       3
 4|       1|       4
 5|       2|       1
 6|       3|       2
 7|       4|       3
 8|       4|       4
 9|       5|       3
10|       5|       4
```

A query like this (with self join):

```
SELECT
  a1.column_1,
  a2.column_1,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a1.column_2 ORDER BY a1.column_2)
FROM agg_test a1
JOIN agg_test a2 ON a1.column_2 = a2.column_2 AND a1.column_1 <> a2.column_1
WHERE a1.column_1 = 1
GROUP BY a1.column_1, a2.column_1
```

Will produce a result like this:

```
column_1|column_1|array_agg
---------------------------
       1|       2|      {1}
       1|       3|      {2}
       1|       4|    {3,4}
       1|       5|    {3,4}
```

We can see that for values 4 and 5 from the joined table we have the same result in the last column. So, is it possible to somehow group the results by it, e.g:

```
column_1|column_1|array_agg
---------------------------
       1|     {2}|      {1}
       1|     {3}|      {2}
       1|   {4,5}|    {3,4}
```

Thanks for any answers. If anything isn't clear or can be presented in a better way - tell me in the comments and I'll try to make this question as readable as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can aggregate by an array.  If you can here is one approach:

```
select col1, array_agg(col2), ar
from (SELECT a1.column_1 as col1, a2.column_1 as col2,
             ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a1.column_2 ORDER BY a1.column_2) as ar
      FROM agg_test a1 JOIN
           agg_test a2
           ON a1.column_2 = a2.column_2 AND a1.column_1 <> a2.column_1
      WHERE a1.column_1 = 1
      GROUP BY a1.column_1, a2.column_1
     ) t
group by col1, ar
```

The alternative is to use `array_dims` to convert the array values into a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a1.column_1,
  ARRAY_AGG(a2.column_1) OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      a1.column_1,
      ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a1.column_2 ORDER BY a1.column_2)
  ) AS "a2.column_1 agg",
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a1.column_2 ORDER BY a1.column_2)
FROM agg_test a1
JOIN agg_test a2 ON a1.column_2 = a2.column_2 AND a1.column_1  a2.column_1
WHERE a1.column_1 = 1
GROUP BY a1.column_1, a2.column_1
;
```

(Highlighted are the parts that are different from the query you've posted in your question.)

The above uses a window `ARRAY_AGG` to combine the values of `a2.column_1` alongside the other other `ARRAY_AGG`, using the latter's result as one of the partitioning criteria. Without the `DISTINCT`, it would produce two `{4,5}` rows for your example. So, `DISTINCT` is needed to eliminate the duplicates.

Here's a SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/df5c3/4

Note, though, that the window `ARRAY_AGG` cannot have an `ORDER BY` like it's "normal" counterpart. That means the order of `a2.column_1` values in the list would be indeterminate, although in the linked demo it does happen to match the one in your expected output.